# How to create input language (e.g. english) with different input keyboard (e.g. Danish)

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I use onenote on OSX and it uses the input language as proofing language so I have two input langauges (English and Danish) however I use both langauges with a Danish hardware keyboard. Any possibility to tweak the English input language to use Danish HW keyboard?

(I know this is possible on Windows but I cannot find the option to do it on OSX)

Comment: Hi, Welcome, Did you try switching the Input key board in System preferences Key Board to Danish?

Comment: Have you already seen the discussion at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_onenote-onenote_mac/proofing-language-changes-each-time-i-go-to-next/82f64b62-96c4-4b1e-b458-6c9cbc2650d4

Comment: @Buscar웃 - that's exactly my question. I want to keep the danish keyboard layout - but change the input language. So have two input languages both of them with Danish keyboard layout.

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, I read that. Others are experincing the same problem. I can live with changing input language but it's really annoying to have the keyboard layout change too - that's why I am asking if anyone know it's possible to change input language and input keyboard separately.

Comment: The difference btw English and Danish keyboard are 3 keys as far I see, so leaving it in E+E is workable solution.

Comment: @Buscar웃 No there is a big difference in layout; Example: this is shift+1,..,0 with DA keyboard: !"#€%&/()= and this is with EN: !@#$%^&*(). There are lots more. Danish has 3 additional vowels too. {} and [] are in difference places, so are :;'" etc. etc.

Comment: Knowing MS, it might take a while to fix that. If you are using the English predominantly maybe a investment in a external keyboard would be worth.

Comment: @Buscar  I don't think another keyboard would make a difference.  He needs a keyboard layout file that has has Danish mapping but which onenote recognizes as English for proofing.

Comment: @Morgan  You could use Ukelele to make a custom keyboard layout that has the name US but has Danish mapping.  Whether this would switch onenote to English proofing I don't know.

Comment: @TomGewecke It's actually works and it very simple to do. 5 minutes and you are good to go! Thanks a lot. Why don't you make it an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ukelele to make a custom keyboard layout which has US as the name but uses the key mapping for Danish.  Hopefully OneNote will switch to English proofing when you use this.

httpL//scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use different keyboard layouts for different languages?

I'm using english as my "input" language, but using the german keyboard layout.

For your system language, go to

> System Preferences > Language & Region

Here are your "input languages".

When you go to

> System Preferences > Keyboard

Just use your preferred one. And **you can easily switch your keyboard layout** through the menu bar:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The original poster wants to use the same keyboard layout for different languages, but needs to have the same layout with two different names to get the right spellcheck activated. Your answer will not help with that.